# SSID rotation prevent tracking or not?

Tags: windows, wifi, audit

The Program [VirtualWifi Manager](https://sw.estiva.org:419/memo/article_aaef2aabefadb49bbc20ccfa163fe0b5.html) can rotate SSID's.

Does rotating SSID's  prevent the  google tracking `_nomap` problem?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. There are sources that indicate that in addition to collecting the SSID, Google is also collecting the BSSID.

> The idea was to take the SSIDs and BSSIDs from the collected packets of data, and to store them in a database together with the information about the location where the SSIDs and BSSIDs were seen.
>   [Source](http://chris.dziemborowicz.com/blog/2010/05/25/google-is-watching/)

and

> Google and others like Apple and Skyhook build a Database which links WLAN BSSIDs to a geographic location. A BSSID is like the MAC Address of a access point that gets broadcasted by that access point.
>   [Source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15009/how-does-google-maps-estimate-my-location-without-gps)

Changing the BSSID of an access point is generally not something most access points let you do since it is tied to the MAC.